# Multiple Login using Facebook & Site Login system - PHP

Tags: php

I create 2 login procedure, with Facebook and site login. But I'm stuck with displaying user information. When users log in from the site system, everything is okay. After user is signed in they display another text `Welcome, $username` but when login with Facebook, nothing. I try with the `while` method, and now I don't know where I'm wrong. My code is:

Site login display after user login:

```
<span><img src="assets/<?php echo htmlentities($result->Vimage1);?>" alt=""></span>
Welcome, <?php echo htmlentities($result->FullName); ?>
```

Facebook login display after user login:

```
if(!empty($userData)){
    $output  = '<h1>Facebook Profile Details </h1>';
    $output .= '<img src="'.$userData['picture'].'">';
    $output .= '<br/>Facebook ID : ' . $userData['oauth_uid'];
    $output .= '<br/>Name : ' . $userData['first_name'].' '.$userData['last_name'];
    $output .= '<br/>Email : ' . $userData['email'];
    $output .= '<br/>Gender : ' . $userData['gender'];
    $output .= '<br/>Locale : ' . $userData['locale'];
    $output .= '<br/>Logged in with : Facebook';
    $output .= '<br/><a href="'.$userData['link'].'" target="_blank">Click to Visit Facebook Page</a>';
    $output .= '<br/>Logout from <a href="'.$logoutURL.'">Facebook</a>';
}
```

While method:

```
<?php
    do {
        if ( isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
            $siteLogin .= ' <div class="header-user-name"> ';
            $siteLogin .= ' <span><img src="assets/userImage/'.htmlentitites($result->Vimage1).'" alt=""></span> ';
            $siteLogin .= ' Welcome, "' . $htmlentities($result->FullName) . '" ';
            $siteLogin .= ' <ul> ';
            $siteLogin .= ' <li><a href="dashboard">Dashboard</a></li> ';
            $siteLogin .= ' <li><a href="profile"> Profile</a></li> ';
            $siteLogin .= ' <li><a href="my-bookings">Bookings</a></li> ';
            $siteLogin .= ' <li><a href="membership">Membershib</a></li> ';
            $siteLogin .= ' <li><a href="logout">Logout</a></li> ';
            $siteLogin .= ' </ul> ';
            $siteLogin .= ' </div> ';
        } if ( isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
            $fbLog .= '  ';
            $fbLogin .= ' <span><img src="'.$userData['picture'].'" alt=""></span> ';
            $fbLogin .= ' Welcome, : ' . $userData['first_name'].' '.$userData['last_name'];
            $fbLog .= ' <ul> ';
            $fbLog .= ' <li><a href="dashboard">Dashboard</a></li> ';
            $fbLog .= ' <li><a href="profile"> Profile</a></li> ';
            $fbLog .= ' <li><a href="my-bookings">Bookings</a></li> ';
            $fbLog .= ' <li><a href="membership">Membershib</a></li> ';
            $fbLog .= ' <li><a href="logout">Logout</a></li> ';
            $fbLog .= ' </ul> ';
            $fbLog .= ' </div> ';
        } while (0);
    }
?>
```

I read this [article](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php) about `while` functions and I don't get what is this for `} while (0);` and am I do good code or not. Thanks for the help and sorry for my bad English. At the end of code, I need to attach this `<div class="show-reg-form modal-open"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i>Sign in</div>` to display user login button. **PS. While method not working.**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be tested by others.
Also check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now can you help me with problem. @Progman